Are these definitions and equality conditions of holder's inequality simutaneously correct?
I am a little lost in the definition of holder's inequality. Unless I did some lazy misunderstanding, it seems that in some places it appears as (i) $$\left( \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i b_i| \right) \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^p \right)^{1/p} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |b_i|^q \right)^{1/q}
$$ while in others (ii) the LHS changes to $\left| \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \overline{b}_i \right|$, generally in the form $$|\langle a,b \rangle| \leq ||a||_p ||b||_q$$
If we consider, in $\mathbb{C}^n$, the equality condition for first case is (as far as I understood) just $$|a_i|^p = \lambda |b_i|^q,  0\leq\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$$ while the second case is just one triangle inequality of "distance" from the first so we would need to have the additional constraint of $a_i \overline{b}_i$ being all colinear/phased , which we can write in many ways, one of them is $$a_i \overline{b}_i = e^{i \theta} |a_i \overline{b}_i|$$ with $\theta$ being a constant for all $i$.
Is the definition of holder's inequality malleable to the context of usage? Are these conditions for equality correct in each scenario?

Wang, Chung-Lie. "Variants of the Hölder inequality and its inverses." Canadian Mathematical Bulletin 20.3 (1977): 377-384.
Here, the author discussed some different forms of Holder's and their equivalence. Maybe it is related
